# If I know the exact location of a file or folder on an Android device, can I put a file there even if it doesn't belong to my app?

Tags: android, file, filesystems

I've been asked to make my android app, at the press of a button, download a file and put it into `/enterprise/device/settings/datawedge/autoimport/`. This location isn't something that my app creates or belongs to my app -- another app on the system reads files from there to import settings.

Is it possible in general to do this kind of thing? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible in general to do this kind of thing?

No. In general, files exist outside of areas where you could possibly get permission to write. That would include `/enterprise/`, `/TKoL/`, or other arbitrarily-named directories off of the system root directory.

On a rooted device, you probably can arrange to write there. And pre-installed system apps might be able to write there.